# Android: Update the contents of ListView even when another activity is active

Tags: android, android-listview

The android app has two activities.

First: MainActivity

Second: AddNewDataActivity

The MainActivityhas a ListView. The user can create a new list view item by clicking on an "Add" button. When the user clicks on the Add button, a AddNewDataActivity is opened and the user fills in some details and saves the work done. Upon saving the work, the activity is finished and the MainActivity comes to front.

Now, before the MainActivity comes to front, I want to update the items in ListView.

Comment: update MainActivity in onResume() according to the changes made in SecondActivity

Answer (score 1):

For this From your `MainActivity` start the `AddNewDataActivity` Activity by calling `StartActivityForResult`() method  not `startActivity()` and in your `AddNewDataActivity` activity when you finish call the method setResult() and pass the data in the Intent  which will call the `onActivityResult()` method in your `MainActivity` here update your `listview`..

here check the example of startActivityForResult()    [**example**](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yous should serialize the Object you create in AddNewActivity and pass it to the main activity as result.
1) start second activity with startActivityForResult(Intent);
2) before calling finish on second activity serialize the object (as json) and put it as bundle extra to the result via setResult();
3) on MainActivity overriede onActivityResult and parse the data from result and add the object to your ArrayList or any data structure you use.

There is another way to do it. Using a singleton where u will have the ArrayList with data and before closing second activity add the object to that ArrayList, and int onActivityResult just refresh the ListView

Here is how to handle onActivityResult
[Transfering data between Activities](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)